# MySQL Combining/Concat/Multiple Select Query

Tags: mysql, select

I have some headache trying to figure out how to create a proper MySQL Query to retrieve the informations I need.
Here is a sample row from my TABLE PARAM :

```
Serial | Repeater1 | Repeater2 | Repeater3
```

I would like to retrieve all the Repeater1, Repeater2 or Repeater3 that are NOT IN the Serial field.
All these fields are under the same SAME TABLE.

For ex :

```
Serial | Repeater1 | Repeater2 | Repeater3

1234   | 1111      | 2222      | null

1235   | 1111      | null      | null

1236   | 1234      | 1111      | 2222
```

My SELECT query should return only :

```
1111

2222
```

As 1234 used in Repeater1 is present in Serial (so need to be avoided) and even if 1111 or 2222 is present under different columns (Repeater2 and Repeater3 in this example) I only wanted to list DISTINCT either Repeater1, Repeater2 or Repeater3 NOT IN Serial.

Do you have any idea to accomplish this REQUEST ?

Many help in advance !

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint use stored procedure with temp tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from ( 
    select distinct Repeater1 as repeater from table1 where Repeater1 is not null 
    UNION 
    select distinct Repeater2 as repeater from table1 where Repeater2 is not null 
    UNION 
    select distinct Repeater3 as repeater from table1 where Repeater3 is not null 
) as datarepeater 
where datarepeater.repeater not in (select serial from table1) and datarepeater.repeater!=0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select r from (
    select Repeater1 as r from t WHERE Repeater1 IS NOT NULL
    union 
    select Repeater2 as r from t  WHERE Repeater2 IS NOT NULL
    union 
    select Repeater3 as r from t  WHERE Repeater3 IS NOT NULL
) reps
left join t
on reps.r = t.Serial 
WHERE t.Serial IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Oto for your help also !